# Long TextArea With CKEditor Split and save as 2 records If More Than 100,000 Characters

Tags: apex, trigger

1. I have already integrated CK Editor With LongtextArea in a `Visualforce Page`.
2. Now it's Working / Save  as well.
3. Now I have an another requirement. LongTextArea allow You to save up to 131,072 Characters only.
4. Even If this Document having 2 lakhs (200,000) Character, it should be split and save into two records.

How I can achieve this process?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you could do that, unless you restrict users to enter text data only. However, you could read and split the data anyways. Assumption: Max characters are less than 200,000

```
var data = CKEDITOR.instances.editorName.getData();
var dataContent = [];
if(data && data.length > 100000){
    dataContent.push(data.substring(0, 100000));
    dataContent.push(data.substring(100000, 200000));
}
```

If you are planning to send such huge data to apex controller, You might come across heap-size error. It would be great if you could post some code after you tried something though, to help you in specific pain-points, rather than giving complete solution.

Answer (score -1):

Really happy to see your valuable response . and i am new to the development, can you please guide me how can i insert your code into my method (were written for save)

```
Public PageReference Save(){
  Document_Template__c dc = New Document_Template__c();
  dc.Template_XML__c = dt.Template_XML__c;
  dc.Account__c = CKEdit;
  System.debug('Account Id | ' + dc.Account__c);
  insert dc;
  PageReference refresh = New PageReference('/'+ CKEdit);
  refresh.setRedirect(true);
  return refresh;
}
```

Regards,
Soundar.